# Find max height

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation

I have stucked with finding max height of an $m$, given only $m, M$ and initial velocity of $m$ - $\vec{V}$. There is no friction in the system. As I understood I need to find $\vec{V_0}$ - velocity of $m$ after it passed the radius, after that it is easy. But to find out $\vec{V_0}$, I need to calculate which amount of energy will be transfered from $m$ to $M$ while $m$ is passing the radius. Could somebody help me with that?

I know that this amount of energy is equivalent to work of centripetal force $+$ work of $m\vec{g}$ $\Delta E=A_{m\vec{a}} + A_{m\vec{g}}$. So we get that $A_{m\vec{a}}=\frac{1}{2}\pi r m\vec{a}$, where $|\vec{a}|$ is $\frac{V^2}{2}$, from here $A_{m\vec{a}}=\frac{1}{2} \pi r m \frac{V^2}{2}$

But if I continue this line that $\Delta E= 1/2 \pi r m \frac{V^2}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \pi r m\vec{g}$, it doesn't corresponds with the answer. Maybe I am missing something?

P.S. answer should be expressed only in given variables (without $t$ and so on...).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using momentum conservation in the $x$ direction we get:

$mv=(M+m)u$

Where $u$ is the velocity of the two masses at the maximum height of $m$.

Also the energy conservation implies that:

$\frac{1}{2}mv^{2}=\frac{1}{2}Mu^{2}+\frac{1}{2}mu^{2}+mgH_{max}$

Where $mgH_{max}$ is the potential energy of $m$ at the maximum height.

From these two equations you can get the desired $H_{max}$.

Comment: thx, it almost led me to the correct answer, but there is one unknown variable - $r$. How can I avoid using it?

Comment: Oh, I understood that $r$ in the formula of conservation of energy is the desired max $h$, isn't it?

Comment: Not exactly. Using the $H_{max}$ in the equation requires some changes:
$\frac{1}{2}mv^{2}=\frac{1}{2}Mu^{2}+mgH_{max}$
Because at the maximum height $m$ has no velocity.

Comment: Oh, I noticed I had a mistake. I fixed my answer above.

Comment: You have only two variables, $u$ and $H_{max}$, don't you?

Comment: Oh, we have only 2 of them.. so its all ok)

Comment: Notice that most of the time, using work in order to solve questions like this is very complicated. The force acting between the two bodies isn't constant, and it changes with time. Therefore, in order to evaluate the work, you need to do an integration. The way above, of course, is much simpler.

Comment: Yes, it is true. Thank you, for guiding me through this)

Answer (score -1):

To answer this question you need to take advantage of two principles:
The conservation of energy
The conservation of linear momentum

When using the conservation of energy, we need to know the kinetic energy the larger block attains in the end as one of the terms. That's why we need to use the conservation of the linear momentum. For both conservations, we consider two points in time: one at the very start, the other as soon as the smaller mass reaches max height.

CONSERVATION OF ENERGY:

Consider the energy of the entire system (small block and big block)

$$E_{before} = \frac{1}{2}mv^2$$
$$E_{after} = mgh + \frac{1}{2}mv_M^2 + \frac{1}{2}Mv_M^2$$
$$\therefore \frac{1}{2}mv^2 = mgh + \frac{1}{2}mv_M^2 + \frac{1}{2}Mv_M^2$$

$h$ is what we are trying to solve for, but $v_M$ is unknown. So let's use the conservation of linear momentum, considering the momentum in the horizontal direction:

CONSERVATION OF LINEAR MOMENTUM

$$P_{before} = mv$$

$$P_{after} = (m+M)v_M$$

$$\therefore v_M = \frac{m}{m+M}v$$

Now, just substitute back into your result for the conservation of energy.